# Root.plist file is not editable

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

```
NSString *DownloadsPlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Root" ofType:@"plist"];
```

My Root.plist file is in setting.bundle but above code is not allowing to read plist file. I want to edit this file how can I do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Main Bundle is read only**.

You cannot edit files that are in main bundle.

You need to copy them to Document Directory for editing them via code.